# Is this €150k beach club bill real?

Tags: economics, social-media

This bill, with a total amount of over €150,000, from a beach club in Monaco is currently [circulating on social media](https://twitter.com/ALEXKONlG/status/869042409203683329). **Is it real?**

I've checked the [website](http://www.nikkibeach.com/destinations/beach-clubs/monaco/cuisine/) of the beach club; some of the more common drinks and dishes on the menu are in the same price range as the bill, but ±25% cheaper. Even if an ordinary ticket printer supports these amounts, it seems somehow inappropriate to present a bill like this to an extravagant customer.

[image]

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure which tags are really appropriate for this question. Feel free to change them.

Comment: The price is dominated by the Midas Armand de Brignac.  So a big part of the question is whether or not you can actually buy such a thing at that price.  [It turns out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armand_de_Brignac) that that actually seems about right - some guy bought one for about the same price in 2011.

Comment: According to that think this would be the current record holder as the previous record was $120K.  I'm siding with this not being true as you would think that it would make some sort of news reports.

Comment: @KAI Yes, that's a very expensive champagne but I'm doubtful they serve it at that beach club. Not impossible, but not in the menu they have online. Also not listed is the Azul Ultra nor is the Roayal Salute, the other 2 large ticket items on that check. http://24n41g3wbd851i2o91ggdslv.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/MonteCarlo_Drinks_List_Menu_2016.pdf

Comment: @ventsyv: I wouldn't expect a menu like that to be complete.  For a luxury establishment like that, there's no way that one page is really their complete wine list.  Likewise, I don't believe they really only offer three kinds of gin.  Presumably the sommelier tells you about the more special options.

Comment: @DenisStallings: Note the currency - the Wikipedia record was GBP 120K.  That's EUR 138K at the current exchange rate, so this one is actually cheaper, without even considering inflation.

Comment: Worth noting that the record was last set in June 2011.  The date on the bill is 26 May 2017 (at 5:01 PM) - less than a week ago.  Can anyone find out who initially submitted the thing to the web?  Might give a bit more yea/nay on credibility.

Comment: @BenBarden That might of been a record in 2011, but people have paid more since then. https://vegas.eater.com/2013/12/13/6314119/meet-the-275000-armand-de-brignac-rose-midas-at-hakkasan

Comment: @BenBarden - The date is very important - the Friday on the Monaco Grand Prix weekend, when (even more than usual) people want to be in Monaco to show how rich they are. (Incidentally, the time of the bill is approximately when I was doing my track walk.) The Fairmont hotel is at the famous hairpin on the grand prix circuit. I see no reason to disbelieve this bill.